# Alguem sabe como se usa uma variavel do tipo array para aceder uma posicao num array do numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Tenho A=np.array([[1,2],3]) e quero usar [0,1] para fazer A[0,1] sendo [0,1] uma variavel. Iria obter 2.
Alguém sabe fazer isto?

Answer (score 1):

Dado:

```
A=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

(O exemplo que você passou cria um array unidimensional em que o primeiro item é uma lista),
Você pode colocar índices multidimensionais que estejam em outras variáveis dentro de colchetes para recuperar um valor - só que esses índices tem necessariamente que ser uma *tupla* (tuple)  de Python - não podem ser outros tipos de sequência:

```
b = [0, 1]
A[tuple(b)]
```

A saída é `2`.

Ou diretamente:

```
b = 0, 1
A[b]
```

(Nesse caso, `b` já é uma tupla - quando não há ambiguidade, os parênteses em volta da tupla são opcionais e `b = 0, 1` é o mesmo que `b = (0, 1)`)

Aproveitando a pergunta, se você estiver interessado em obter fatias (slices) das arrays da mesma forma, para as quais, a notação literal é feita com o uso de `:`:

```
In [69]: A = np.array(range(25))

In [70]: A.shape=(5,5)

In [71]: A
Out[71]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])


In [73]: A[1:4,1:4]
Out[73]: 
array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [16, 17, 18]])
```

Você deve criar a tupla, do mesmo jeito, e usar objetos do tipo `slice` para ter o mesmo efeito que a notação `inicio:fim[:passo]`:

```
In [74]: b = slice(1,4), slice(1, 4)

In [75]: A[b]
Out[75]: 
array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [16, 17, 18]])
```

Se for usar para algum eixo a notação de `...` (elllipsis), o nome `...`  corresponde ao objeto `Ellipsis` (parecido com o None: só existe um, etc...), e você tanto pode usar esse nome quando os próprios `...` na sua tupla:

```
b = slice(1,4), ... 
# ou
b = slice(1,4), Ellipsis
```

Saída:

```
In [81]: A[b]
Out[81]: 
array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

E por fim, só para cobrir todos os aspectos, em alguns casos mesmo podendo ter os índices como uma tupla, precisamos ter um objeto que seja chamável como uma função e retorne um elemento do Array - a sintaxe de `[ ]` não é o suficiente. (sim, normalmente você vai estar programando algo bastante avançado pra chegar a tanto) - nesses casos, você pode usar direto o método `__getitem__` do array:

```
sum(map(A.__getitem__, [(0, 0), (1,1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]) )
```

Vai recuperar os elementos nas posições indicadas na sequência e somar seus valores, por exemplo. (Atenção - isso é um exemplo, há várias formas mais legíveis e melhores de fazer isso - nesse caso, por exemplo: `sum(A.diagonal())` ). E por fim, para quem não se sente a vontade de chamar diretamente os métodos dunder - no caso o `__getitem__`, pode se usar a função `getitem` do módulo `operator`, passando o array como primeiro parâmetro:

```
from operator import getitem
from functools import partial

sum(map(partial(getitem, A), [(0, 0), (1,1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]) )
```

Acho que isso cobre o tópico por completo.